# Does the Thief card work for a dwarf with broken equipment in Saboteur 2?

Tags: saboteur-2

The rules for Saboteur 2 specifically state that the **Theft** card does not work for a dwarf who is **Trapped!**. Does the Theft card work for a dwarf who is not Trapped! but who does have broken equipment?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**,

There is no reason per the rules to suspect that **Theft** does not work for someone who is trapped.  As one exception for Theft is explicitly listed (**Trapped!**), someone would need to make a compelling argument as to why broken equipment should keep Theft from working.